# use spark in flask-uwsgi-nginx project no module pyspark issue

Tags: python, nginx, apache-spark, flask, uwsgi

I use spark to do some stuff in flask-uwsgi-nginx project.
when I run:

runserver.py

```
if __name__=='__main__':
app.run(debug=False)
```

it will work!

but when use uwsgi-nginx to run the project in background(daemon)
the error will occur with following logs:

```
ImportError: No module named pyspark
```

I had set the $PYTHONPATH to `/pathtospark/python`, so it can work with runserver.py.
I also set the $PYTHONPATH in /etc/environment and execute `echo $PYTHONPATH` when sudo to root.
It will return the right $PYTHONPATH...

Can anyone tried the spark-flask-uwsgi-nginx?

PS:
I had tried to set PYTHONPATH in uwsgi ini file by

```
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/spark/python
```

but it didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by the following settings in uwsgi ini file

```
env = PYTHONPATH=/pathtospark/python
env = SPARK_HOME=/pathtospark
```